# Pascal bounds checking (standard)

Tags: runtime-error, standards, pascal, error-checking

A simlpe question: does Pascal include bounds checking in the original standard (ISO 7185)?

I can not see it mentioned there anywhere (http://www.pascal-central.com/standards.html) or may be I am only blind.

I know that in some Pascal compilers I can choose where to check bounds or not, the importnt for me is that how is it in that standard.

Comment: Whether the compiler enforces bounds checking is implementation specific, and is not specified in the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked at the standard in while, so my knowledge is a little rusty, but yes, bounds checking is included in the standard (ISO 7185). The standard requires that 1. array indexes be valid (see [Indexed-variables](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.5.3.2%20Indexed-variables)), and 2. all values are assignment compatible with the variable being assigned to (see [assignment compatibility](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.4.6%20Assignment-compatibility)).

However the standard also states that an error is "A violation by a program of the requirements of this International Standard that a processor is permitted to leave undetected" (see [Error](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#3.1%20Error)). Invalid array indexing and out of range assignments are violations of that standard, and are errors.

Comment: That's a good find. It also states, *Processors **should** attempt the detection of as many errors as possible, and to as complete a degree as possible. **Permission to omit detection is provided for implementations in which the detection would be an excessive burden.*** Thus, the compiler option whether to check index bounds.

Comment: thank you very much for your anwers :) I really appreciate it, it would took me a lot of time to find it

Comment: Does that really mean that index checking is mentioned? I don't think so. It is also bad form to access an uninitialzed variable, but nothing in the language prevents me from doing it, IOW not everything that is not allowed requires a check.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, If you look at the link I provided you will see, "the value of the index-expression shall be assignment-compatible with the index-type of the array-type". So for example, if you have a[1..10] of int; then a[0] is an error because 0 is not assignment compatible with the type 1..10.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, actually accessing uninitialized variables is an error according to the standard. To quote, "When a factor is used, it shall be an error if the variable denoted by a variable-access of the factor is undefined." See the first few lines of this http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.7 Expressions.

Comment: Yes, it is an error, and that is why I chose it as an example. But my point: there is no "accessing uninitialzed variable" check either. Using an index beyond the bounds is indeed an error, but the standard does not seem to require a bounds check anywhere, just like it does not require a check against uninitiliazed variables. In other words, I don't see the standard explicitly not implicitly demand a bounds check for arrays.

Comment: Do you know what "assignment compatible" means? ISTM that you don't. Assignment compatiblity deals with type, not with value.This has NOTHING to do with bounds checking.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, If you read the link to "assignment compatibility in my answer above you will see that it starts with "A value of type T2 shall be designated assignment-compatible with a type T1 if ...". So by definition assignment compatibility is about values being compatible with types, not just about types. Please feel free to quote from the standard to back up your statements if you disagree. Actually, I hope you don't because I don't really want to get into a debate about what the standard means.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, it occurs to me that maybe we are not talking about the same version of the standard. The question specifically referred to ISO 7185, any my answer/comments apply only to that version.

Comment: We are talking about the same standard. I don't see the standard explicitly nor implicitly mentioning (runtime) bounds checking. You somehow interpret that in the way you said, but I don't follow that interpretation. Assignment compatibility has absolutely nothing to do with this, and the requirement that indexes (indices?) be valid does not necessarily imply runtime bounds checking. There is also the requirement that variables are initialized before use, and that doesn't seem to imply any checking for that case, or does it?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Do you agree that given x : 1..10; that the assignment statement x := 100; is an out of bounds assignment? Do you also agree that 100 is not assignment compatible with the type of x (i.e. 1..10)? If so how do you interpret 1. "... values SHALL be assignment compatible with the type possessed ..." (in the definition of assignment statements). 2. "At any place where the rule of assignment-compatibility is used it shall be an error if ..." (in the definition of assignment compatibility). I don't have enough space to quote the full definition so I put in some ... markers.

Comment: Yes, it is out of bounds. But assignment compatibility means that I can assign an integer to a subrange ***type***. That the value may be out of range is another issue and nothing in the standard says that this requires the language to check this, it only says that it is an error, but not that it should be checked at runtime. So no, the standard does not *require* bounds checking. FWIW, you still seem to misunderstand assignment compatibility. That deals with ***types***, not with ***values***. Integers and integer subrange types ***are*** assignment compatible.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, ok, we are making progress. So you agree that, according to the standard, the assignment above is an error. If you look at the definition of an error (including the notes), see link in my answer above. You should see that the standard says errors SHOULD be reported. The definition of compliant processors (see "www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#5.1 Processors") gives processors 3 choices for handling errors. 1. document the errors not reported, 2. report the error before running the program, or 3. report the error during execution of the program.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, by the way, the question that was asked was whether the standard includes bounds checking, not whether the standard REQUIRES bounds checking.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, again you claim assignment compatibility deals with types not with values (and again, you do not quote from the standard to back up your claim. So your claim is true because you say it is?). Again I quote from the standard's DEFINITION of assignment compatibility "A VALUE of type T2 shall be designated assignment-compatible with a type T1 if any of the following five statements is true:". The third statement that follows is "c) T1 and T2 are compatible ordinal-types, and the value of type T2 is in the closed interval specified by the type T1." How do you interpret this?

Comment: That you should not assign 100 to a subrange type of, say, 1..10. That still does not require bound checking. It simply declares it an error.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, ok, we seem to be having a private debate here, and we are not getting anywhere, so it looks like we will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Ok let's do that. We disagree.